# Typeface of “La Maison Tellier” (1929)

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to find the typeface used in this edition of *La Maison Tellier* by *Guy de Maupassant* published in Paris in 1929 by Louis Conard:

[image: Typical page]

[image: Title page]

(I tried an automated tool, but it didn't work.)

Comment: Take a better photo, or scan the document at a higher resolution, then automated font identifiers might work.

Comment: You indicated you used 'an' automated tool; could you tell us which one? Please have a look at [our requirements for font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/5498) and try and [edit] your question to follow those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is (I think): Romain du Roi, or Grandjean Corps 20. I looked it up in the following reference: *An Introduction to the History of Printing Types*, by Geoffrey Dowding, 1961. See page 78, for an illustration of Grandjean Corps 20, which seems to be an exact match.

[image]

Comment: No, it's close, but not exact. Look at the bottom of the 'c'.

Comment: It's embarrasing to accept my own answer. But it's the best match. The problem with the 'c' might be an error in the reproduction of the text, because the 'c' s don't all match 100%.

Comment: No reason to shame. None of us bothered to check historical sources.

Comment: Yes, this is it (probably a recut copy). The key signs are the symmetrical serifs on the 'b', 'd' and other characters and the lower-case 'L' with a notch, based on calligraphy of the period.

Answer (score 2):

The font appears to be Romain Text/Romain Headline.

It can be purchased from [Swiss Typefaces](https://www.swisstypefaces.com)

[image]

Image showing the Rs matching as called out by [Phillip](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/102069/philipp)

[image]

Comment: It looks similar, but not exactly the same: look at the lower right end of the capital R. It extends more in the font you suggest than in the original post

Comment: I don't think you're correct. If you line them up it's a near perfect match. Even with the scans not being flat. See my updated answer.

Comment: You may be right. I didn’t want to force you into extra work. +1

Comment: No worries, just ensuring accuracy!

Answer (score 0):

The only resemblant I saw is SangBleu Serif. It's a little too thin, but there's no SangBleu Serif Reqular available.

[image]

It's sold by Swiss Typefaces. It has been available since 2008, so it probably is an engineered version of that old book font.